# Problem with Extreme Learning Machine code

Tags: r, machine-learning, graph, neural-network

I am trying to run an ELM code, and apparently the code is correct. However, the plotted graph is not what is was supposed to be. Could anyone help?

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovXd8.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMdhv.png)

```
library("corpcor")
library("mlbench")

y_final <- function(xvec,z, w,par){
  if(par==1){
    xvec<-c(1,xvec)}
  u<-xvec %*% z #1x3 * 3x30
  u<-u %*% w #3x30 * 30x1
  y<-1.0*(u>=0)
  return ((as.matrix(y))) 
}

p<-10 #number of neurons
nc<-2
a<-mlbench.spirals(100,sd = 0.05)
X<-a[["x"]] 
Y<-as.numeric(a[["classes"]])
Y[Y==2]<--1

Z<-replicate(p, runif(nc+1,-0.5,.5))
Xaug<-as.matrix(cbind(1,X))
Y<-as.numeric(Y)

H<-tanh( as.matrix(Xaug) %*% Z ) #100x3 * 3x30
w<-pseudoinverse(H) %*% Y #30x100 * 100x1

Yhat<-round(H %*% w)

seq<-seq(-1,1,.01)
M<-matrix(nrow = length(seq), ncol = length(seq))

for (i in 1:length(seq)){
  for (j in 1:length(seq)){
    x1<-seq[i]
    x2<-seq[j]
    x1x2<-matrix(cbind(x1,x2))
    M[i,j]<-y_final(x1x2,Z,w,1)
  }
}

filled.contour(seq,seq,M, nlevels=5,xlim=range(-1,1), ylim=range(-1,1), plot.axes ={axis(1); axis(2);points(X,col = Y + 2)})
```

Comment: What exactly is the graph supposed to be?

Comment: the outline of the background colors should separate the classes of the green and black points